# Displaying multiple values from same column in one row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm working on a Stored procedure, to extend it with one function here on my job. At the moment I have a problem in displaying multiple values from the same column in one row, and they have to be differed and presented like this **25,26,27**

So this is what I've been trying.

```
DECLARE @myVariable varhcar(200) null)
SELECT @myVariable = COALESCE(@myVariable + '','','') + stringvalue
from TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 = SOMEVARIABLE
and ISSUE = COLUMN2

SELECT @Headtext = 'name' + convert(varchar, @myVariable)
```

Before this in the SP I create a table, into which it displays other data. I want the SP to create rows with this data aswell. Still got some troubles not sure have to this, first timer with this kind of SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
DECLARE @myVariable varhcar(200);
SELECT @myVariable = COALESCE(@myVariable + ',', '') + stringvalue
from TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 = SOMEVARIABLE and ISSUE = COLUMN2;

SELECT @Headtext = 'name' + @myVariable;
```

Another way to concatenate the variables is:

```
SELECT @myVariable = stuff((select ',' + stringvalue
                            from TABLE
                            WHERE COLUMN1 = SOMEVARIABLE and ISSUE = COLUMN2
                            for xml path ('')
                           ), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @Headtext = 'name' + @myVariable;
```